# SSAS: Programmatically create attribute relationships

Tags: c#, ssas, dimension

Using AMO I can happily confirm the existance of two dimension attributes.  I'd like to create a relationship.  The following (result) returns a result code of 0 what ever that means however after processing the cube there is no relation.  Suggestions?

```
 // confirm db exists
 db = objServer.Databases.FindByName(strCubeDBName);

// find the dimension
  string dimName = "Product";
  Dimension dim = db.Dimensions.FindByName(dimName);

attrSource = dim.Attributes.FindByName("Spanish Product Subcategory Name");
if (attrSource != null)
    Console.WriteLine(attrSource + " - source attribute exists");
else
    throw new Exception(attrSource + " - source attribute does not exist");


attrRelated = dim.Attributes.FindByName("French Product Subcategory Name");
if (attrRelated != null)
    Console.WriteLine(attrRelated + " - Related attribute exists");
else
    throw new Exception(attrRelated + " - Related attribute does not exist");

int result;

result = attrSource.AttributeRelationships.Add(new AttributeRelationship(attrRelated));
Console.WriteLine(result);

dim.Process(ProcessType.ProcessUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the new attribute relationship, you need to call Update on the dimension. In your code above, just before calling `Process`, add the following line:

```
dim.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull | UpdateOptions.AlterDependents)
```